# c#, hide "controlbox", winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I just don't know how to explain my problem. So I have created an image.

(I am not using WPF)

[image]

---

So now I have problem connected with my old problem.

Now I have the new "cool" border around my form.

But it is working only when I use `FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow` or `FormBorderStyle.Sizable` otherwise it is "borderless".

But I wanna have non-resizable form...

My poor solution:

I can use `maximumsize = this.size;` and `minimumsize = this.size` but when I put my cursor over the border then my cursor changes to "resize" cursor... and that is ugly...

I hope you will understand me.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set your form to have no title and also to, as you say, hide the control box. You can change both of these in the **Properties** panel for your form.

Or, in code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ControlBox = false;
    Text = "";
}
```

Note that this will cause your form to be undraggable (if it's not already resizable), and you need to add your own control to handle closing the form.

**EDIT:** one way to prevent the window from being resizable *and* prevent the cursor from changing to the resize handles is to override the `WndProc()` handler for the form and intercept `WM_NCHITTEST`.

Place this method in your form class, and keep the `FormBorderStyle` as `FormBorderStyle.Sizable` or `FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow`:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message) 
{ 
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084; 

    if (message.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
    {
        return; 
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```